# Lucene Highlighter throws IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, lucene, highlighting

The exception i get:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot create Token Stream from Terms without offsets
```

My code: (creating TokenStream throws exception)

```
Highlighter hl = new Highlighter(new SimpleHTMLFormatter(), new QueryScorer(titleQuery));
hl.setTextFragmenter(new NullFragmenter());
String text = searcher.doc(scoreDocs[i].doc).get("title");
TokenStream ts = TokenSources.getAnyTokenStream(searcher.getIndexReader(), scoreDocs[i].doc, "title", analyzer);
String frag = hl.getBestFragment(ts, text);
```

Here's how the **title** field is indexed:

```
FieldType ft = new FieldType();
ft.setIndexed(true);
ft.setStored(true);
ft.setStoreTermVectors(true);
ft.setStoreTermVectorOffsets(true);
ft.setStoreTermVectorPositions(true);
doc.add(new Field("title", title, ft));
```

This is baffling to me as I am clearly storing Terms w/ offsets and positions

I tried `ft.setIndexOptions(FieldInfo.IndexOptions.DOCS_AND_FREQS_AND_POSITIONS_AND_OFFSETS)` but it didn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You forget to add setTokenized(true). Do as following, it should work.

```
    FieldType type = new FieldType();
    type.setIndexed(true);
    type.setIndexOptions(FieldInfo.IndexOptions.DOCS_AND_FREQS_AND_POSITIONS_AND_OFFSETS);
    type.setStored(true);
    type.setStoreTermVectors(true);
    type.setTokenized(true);
    type.setStoreTermVectorOffsets(true);
```

For detail please refer : [Highlighting In Lucene](http://computergodzilla.blogspot.com/2013/07/how-to-use-lucene-highlighter.html)